# How do I create a new route table on rooted Android?

Tags: file-system, router

On Linux I can type something like `echo 202 my_table >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and voila, I can use my_table in commands like `ip route add 1.1.1.1 dev eth0 table my_table`.

But my rooted Android phone doesn't have `/etc/iproute2`. And even if I create this directory (`mkdir -p /etc/iproute2/`), then `echo 202 my_table >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and run `ip route add 1.1.1.1 dev eth0 table my_table` I get :

```
Error: argument "my_table" is wrong: "table" value is invalid
```

How to create and delete route tables on Android?

Comment: It's `/data/misc/net/rt_tables` on Android. But Android's limited `ip` command doesn't read `rt_tables` at all. You need to build `iproute2` package. Be noted that routing on Android is far complex than normal Linux distros.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Can you point to some documentation on routing on Android works?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, Android doesn't use `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.

You can, instead of a name, use a new table ID number.  E.g.,

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1 dev eth0 table 10
```